# Custom Home/Index route in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a custom route for the home controller on the index action with a required property ie. `localhost/{something}`

Would think adding something like this would work

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "HomeUrlKey",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{urlKey}");
```

before the default route, with the home controller having

```
[Route("HomeUrlKey")]
public IActionResult Index(string urlKey)
{
    return View("HomeLocation");
}
```

I've also created a view called `HomeLocation.cshtml` - but no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you use this tutorial to achive a fundamental understanding of routing in MVC [Getting started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the controller needed to be

```
 [Route("/{urlKey:alpha}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string urlKey)...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-constraints